# Can't get last value from JSON

Tags: android, arrays, json, eclipse, string

I'm trying to get all value from a JSON API, I've managed to get almost all of them, except one! As you can see, this is the JSON output from the server. (I can't change it)

```
{
   "error":"",
   "S8tf":{
      "infoToken":"wCfhXe",
      "deleteToken":"gzHTfGcF",
      "size":122484,
      "sha1":"8c4e2bbc0794d2bd4f901a36627e555c068a94e6",
      "filename":"Screen_Shot_2013-07-02_at_3.52.23_PM.png"
   },
   "S29N":{
      "infoToken":"joRm6p",
      "deleteToken":"IL5STLhq",
      "size":129332,
      "sha1":"b4a03897121d0320b82059c36f7a10a8ef4c113d",
      "filename":"Stockholmsyndromet.docx"
   }
}
```

As you can see, each string/"array" begins with a "fileId" this is randomly generated from the server. I'm using the code below, I can see all values like: filename, size, sh1 etc. But I can't seem to figure out how to get the "fileId". The fileId is (in this json) S8tf and S29N

My code:

```
public class FilesActivity extends SherlockActivity {

    private static String TAG_FILENAME = "filename";
    private static String TAG_SIZE = "size";
    private static String TAG_ITOKEN = "infoToken";
    private static String TAG_DTOKEN = "deleteToken";
    private static String TAG_SHA1 = "sha1";

    private ListView lv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.dblist);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Files");

        String response = null;
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        ResponseHandler <String> resonseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost("http://api.bayfiles.net/v1/account/files?session=of1903u3pj43c3can8rc33gc42");

        try {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
               json.put("filename", "error");

               postMethod.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(json.toString().getBytes("UTF8")));
               postMethod.setHeader( "Content-Type", "application/json" );
               response = httpClient.execute(postMethod,resonseHandler);
               TextView txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.nodata);
               JSONObject request = new JSONObject(response);
               for (Iterator<?> keyIterator = request.keys(); keyIterator.hasNext(); ) {
                   String key = (String) keyIterator.next();
                   JSONObject object = request.optJSONObject(key);

                   ArrayList<fileObject> objectList = new ArrayList<fileObject>();
                   if (object != null) {
                       //Setting TAGs
                       TAG_FILENAME = object.getString("filename");
                       TAG_SIZE = object.getString("size");
                       TAG_ITOKEN = object.getString("infoToken");
                       TAG_DTOKEN = object.getString("deleteToken");
                       TAG_SHA1 = object.getString("sha1");            


                       txt.setText(
                               TAG_FILENAME + "\n"
                               + TAG_SIZE + "\n"
                               + TAG_ITOKEN + "\n"
                               + TAG_DTOKEN + "\n"
                               + TAG_SHA1 + "\n"
                               + txt.getText()
                               );                      

                       Log.d("log_tag", object.getString("filename"));
                   }
               }           
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {      
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("log_tag", "Error: " + e.toString());

        }
    }
}
```

If you didn't get it, I'm trying to catch the value from fileId aka S8tf and S29N, these are random numbers and produced by the server.

EDIT: Got it working thanks to you guys! Since I know it's irritating that the poster figure it out, and you can't, what I did is to put String fileId = key; Inside my object loop, like this:

```
if (object != null) {
    fileObject obj = new fileObject();
    obj.setFileId(key);
    obj.setFileName(object.getString("filename"));
    obj.setSize(object.getString("size"));
    obj.setInfoToken(object.getString("infoToken"));
    obj.setDeleteToken(object.getString("deleteToken"));
    obj.setSha1(object.getString("sha1"));

    objectList.add(obj);
    Log.d("fileId", key); // Shows both of the values!
}
```

Comment: your fileId is in the 'key' variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look at the first part of your for loop...

```
JSONObject request = new JSONObject(response);

for (Iterator<?> keyIterator = request.keys(); keyIterator.hasNext(); ) {

         String key = (String) keyIterator.next();
         JSONObject object = request.optJSONObject(key);
```

You request all of the keys from the JSONObject that represents your response from the server.  These keys are the values you are looking for.  If you were to add a

`System.out.println(key);`

after the first line in your loop, you will see the values printed out ('error','S8tf', ...).

Comment: Sorry, i now got both of the names, like S8tf and S29N

Comment: Oh sorry, forgot we were in Android.. Debug and check the value of key or use Log.v() to see what the value is.  Yes, since you are in a for loop, you should get multiple log statements. Does that solve your problem?

Comment: I got it working, thanks to you :) No problem :) Thank you very much! Only putet inside the "if object" loop :)

Answer (score 2):

I just looked at the [JSONObject documentation](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html):

I feel like the getNames()-method could be what you are searching for.